# Change layout to horizontal when exporting from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

please advise how to change layout to horizontal when exporting data from Excel to Word.
I need to change layout on Word since it cuts the data on the right.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please take time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You could start by recording a macro in Word which will give you the objects, properties, and syntax you require.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on :), but you could use transpose.  This takes 2 cols 5 rows and makes 5 cols 2 rows?

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range

Set r = Range("a1:b5")

Range("n1").Resize(r.Columns.Count, r.Rows.Count) = Application.Transpose(r)

End Sub
```

Comment: "I need to change layout on Word since it cuts the data on the right." - making the data even wider wouldn't help as then even more of the "data on the right" would be cut. OP is clearly suggesting they want to change the Word page layout.

Comment: Apologies, i read the title as the data layout rather than page layout.